# Center the items of listview horizontally

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` whose single item  have a `RelativeLayout` which contains many elements , now i have `RelativeLayout` set to wrap_content in height and a certain width. What i want to display is horizontally center the `RelativeLayout`. `ListView` spans horizontally and vertically to full as it has also wrap_content in height and width.

Also i don't want to include another layout.

Comment: @user13  it has Relative layout as root and many other elements like image,button etc inside it.

Comment: @user13 let me check but since relative layout has many elements, i am pretty sure it will not work.

Comment: @user13 gravity is for inner elements, i want relative layout to be centered.

Comment: @user13 its not working.

Comment: @user13 again not working..

Answer (score 0):

Change `RelativeLayout` width to `match_parent`. and manage all inner views as yout require.

Comment: i cannot center the inner views .. and it is not what i asked. I want to center relative layout.

Comment: okay, are u tried by changing `ListView` width as `match_parent` and `RelativeLayout`'s `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`?